# Can't change vm.max_map_count on LXC

Tags: elasticsearch, lxc

I try running Elasticsearch 6.x on LXC using Ansible, when try to start Elasticsearch service in elasticsearch log I see:

```
[2020-01-04T08:45:58,744][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [4WUODd8] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

when I searched for this I found :

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

but When I running this I get :

```
sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system
```

I tried change file manually but didn't work , Is there any way change this environment variable in LXC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by executing command :

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

on Ansible hosts it self